# How did Mon-El know English?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

When Mon-El arrives on Earth, he’s in a Kryptonian pod. He then spends a while in a coma. When he wakes up, he apparently speaks English, though he has some trouble with certain phrases:

> MON-EL: This is awe and some.
>
> WINN: No…no, it’s just awesome. You gotta put those two words
> together, you’ll be golden.
>
> <sub>*Supergirl*, “Survivors”</sub>

Mon-El also implies that he learned English:

> MON-EL: I’m sorry, English is my second language.
>
> <sub>*Supergirl*, “Medusa”</sub>

Kara and Kal had the benefit of an upbringing by human families, who (living in the United States), could well have taught them English, but Mon-El didn’t.

Did Mon-El already know English? Do most aliens? And if so, how? (Perhaps [super-telepathy](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/superman/4005-1807/forums/supermans-telepathic-powers-1583442/)?) Or did he learn it quickly somehow?

Comment: Most aliens we see already know English. Are you singling Mon-El out because he arrived in a coma? I think Kara knew English before coming to Earth. (Seems like Space Aliens know English, for reasons).

Comment: @CreationEdge - I don’t think there’s any evidence that Kara knew English before arriving on Earth. I think that we just had a translation convention going on for Kryptonian scenes, since subtitles would be a pain. There’s definitely at least one Kryptonian language (we hear some words from it), so that seems most likely. As for “most aliens,” we generally see people with a lot of backstory, and thus plenty of time to learn Earth languages. They’re usually portrayed as having their own languages too.

Comment: But if most aliens do actually know English before coming to Earth, the question stands, it’s just a lot broader.

Comment: [This clip](https://youtu.be/20kOgj3t9d0)  Is right after Supes finds Kara and takes her to the Danvers. She seems to understand English (but only the mother has any lines). Dunno if that helps anyone.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Hmm. Well, it’s still possible that she doesn’t know what’s being said (she looks a bit lost). But it might be worth editing the question nonetheless.

Comment: If you see how to fit it in. Was mostly hoping to offer guidance. Not sure if I'll be able to do more myself. On mobile and editing is terrible on it.

Comment: What's to explain? It's just another Kryptonian superpower — the innate ability to speak English when under the rays of a yellow sun. Makes as much sense as all those other superpowers.Super breath?

Comment: @user14111 - That is certainly a perfectly fine explanation, but I am hoping the show or writers said something that might back that up.

Comment: @CreationEdge - In the most recent episode of *Supergirl*, Kara and Clark find an alien (on an alien planet) who can speak decent English, and are perplexed by this (it turns out that the alien met an English-speaking human once). This suggests that if an alien knows an Earth language without having learned it, there’s probably an explanation.

Comment: I took it as a narrative short-cut. By all rights, Mon-El would have been speaking either Daxam's native language (which MAY be Kryptonian, or a dialect of same, considering the TV show gave Krypton and Daxam a more connected history) or perhaps Interlac, which Kara would know how to speak as well.

Kara was sent to Earth as a child, so she likely got some form of sleep-teaching during the trip. Mon-El may have as well, but I don't think he was planning to go to Earth...?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I thought that in the comics a) the kryptonians knew of earth (and potentially the languages), b) Jor-El researched earth quite heavily and specifically selected the planet, the country (and even the family) he sent his child to (so perhaps the family prepared her) and c) the ships which took them to earth were extremely technologically advanced - sustaining life for several years, etc. I thought that there'd be some program or manner in which the occupants were taught the language whilst in suspended animation while en route to earth.

Comment: Hey! Mind providing the information about which comic this is from?

Comment: Superman arrived as a baby, so ther was no need to -pre-teach him English. The stories about Jor-El specifically changing any one family are quite varied, and are largely seen to be out of continuity. Elliot S. Maggin wrote one where Jor-El contacted Einstein, planning to send his baby directly to the scientist.